# JPA: stateless session beans and managed entities

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Lets assume I have an JPA Entity called `Foo` with a `String myStr` property;

When I now define a stateless session bean like this:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class FooBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="foo-pu")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Foo getFoo(int id) {
         return em.find(Foo.class,id);
    }

    public void changeMyStr(Foo entity) {
         entity.setMyStr("fooStr");
    }

}
```

Will the changes made in `changeMyStr()` become persisted if I pass a previously acquired `Foo` object through `getFoo()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your calls to `getFoo(...)` and `changeMyStr(...)` are made inside the same transaction, changes to the `Foo` instance should become persisted, if that transaction was commited. Entities typically become detached once you leave the transaction, so if you invoke `getFoo(...)` in one transaction and `changeMyStr(...)` in another, changes made inside `changeMyStr(...)` (and any other changes made outside the original transaction) will *not* be persisted.

If you use an [extended persistence context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType.html#EXTENDED), entities will *not* become detached when leaving the original transaction, but that is a rather unusual case. Read [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/extended_persistence_context_in_stateful) or [this one](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/extended_pc/extended.html) for more details.

Comment: ... and by default each method in a StatelessSessionBean takes place within its own transaction.

Comment: Thank you for this well explained answere. Should I rather call `em.merge()` in `changeMyStr()` (which actually does some business logic in my concrete case) or should I rather acquire the entity inside the method using `em.find()`.

Comment: @Paranaix the more orthodox option would be to have some method in a higher layer that implements the whole transactional business logic. This method would then invoke `getFoo(...)`, `changeMyStr(...)` and other data access "primitives" *inside the same transaction*. In this way, your entities would not become detached and everything would work as is meant to do. If for some reason this is not feasible, then using `em.merge(...)`would be a reasonable option.